# Mysql Select From Select Syntax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What is the error in this query:

```
SELECT cnt,COUNT(*) AS total FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,cod_documento FROM op_documentosxmateriais 
    GROUP BY cod_documento)
GROUP BY cnt
```

Phpmyadmin returns:

Static analysis:

6 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 34)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 42)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 137)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "GROUP BY" at position 144)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "GROUP BY" at position 144)

Comment: What are you trying to do? This query doesn't seems right? a probably [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? I suspect it's outdated because when I use the query (corrected by Barmar below) I don't get any warnings in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is that MySQL requires that every subquery used in `FROM` or `JOIN` must have an alias, so it should be:

```
SELECT cnt,COUNT(*) AS total FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,cod_documento FROM op_documentosxmateriais 
    GROUP BY cod_documento) AS x
GROUP BY cnt
```

It looks like PhpMyAdmin has its own syntax checker that's not behaving the same as MySQL itself.